# UK, Office of National Statistics, personal or organisational right to deny data requests

Tags: united-kingdom, parliamentary-law

In the UK, the [Office for National Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_for_National_Statistics) regularly

> produces and publishes a wide range of the information about the United Kingdom that can be used for social and economic policy-making as well as painting a portrait of the country as its population evolves over time. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_for_National_Statistics#Purpose_and_scope) article)

My question is whether the status of the ONS as an executive office of a non-ministerial department (reporting directly to Parliament) gives it the right to request (/demand) data (for example, for the production of a particular indicator that has been requested by Parliament), or advice, without paying for it.

As has been pointed out in the comments, the UK National Census may be one example of an ONS survey where a citizen does not have the right to refuse to answer. I am specifically interested in whether the ONS has the general right to insist on answers/demand other data (i.e. not tied to any specific named survey), without paying for them.

Comment: This looks like a legal question rather than a political one.

Comment: Fair enough, point taken. Do you consider that it would be better on Law stackexchange, or would they say that it is too specific to the UK?

Comment: @OliP I would try Law.SE

Comment: @Machavity thanks, moderator flag raised with this request

Comment: I will migrate this question to Law.SE at the request of the author of the question.

Comment: Shall we try answering his question?

Comment: Could you supply some examples of the ONS doing this?

Comment: @Steve: the [National Census](https://www.ons.gov.uk/census/censustransformationprogramme/confidentiality) is one obvious and nationwide example, but the function of the ONS is to gather data by survey; it would be interesting to know where and when respondents may refuse to answer.

Comment: @TimLymington I have expanded the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of itself, no.

The power to compel answers would need to come from statute - either the statute that created the body or a statute relating to a particular data gathering effort.

Comment: See: https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/transparencyandgovernance/onsdatapolicies/legislationondata